# stdout of subprocess.Popen not working correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am unable to save  my output of `subprocess.Popen` correctly. I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/em0Xd.png) in the file I chose. The directory specified is correct, as just above I told it to erase text already existing in it, which worked. Any solutions to this?
Code is below

```
f = open("hunter_logs.txt", "w")
subp = subprocess.Popen(
                        'docker run -p 5001-5110:5001-5110/udp -v D:\Hunter\hunter\hunter-scenarios:/hunter-scenarios europe-west3-docker.pkg.dev/hunter-all/controller-repo/hunter_controller:latest -d /hunter-scenarios  -s croatia -i OPFOR', stdout=f)
```

Comment: What output would you expect?

Comment: The one that appears in the python console.

Comment: Try either adding *shell=True* to your `Popen` command or instead of passing a single string to `Popen` as your command, pass a list of strings: `['docker', 'run', '-p', etc.]`

Answer (score 0):

Probably the process is outputting some of its logs to `stderr` and some to `stdout`. Add `stderr=f` as another argument to `Popen()` in order to capture both streams to the same file.

Comment: Perfect, works now! Thanks!